# Manga where the lowest level demon lord is killed by the hero then reincarnated as the hero’s best friend

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

It is a manga about the lowest level demon lord and he has to fight the “hero” of his universe and he tries to call for help from the second or third strongest demon lord because she used to have a crush on him or something. But she’s too late.

The hero didn’t want to kill him but one of her party members stabbed him. Then he’s reborn and now he’s the hero’s best friend. He then makes it his mission to make her even stronger to defeat the demon lord faster so he can be lazy.

Comment: when you say that the weak demon lord was reborn as the hero's best friend, does this mean that his soul went into the hero's friend at the time of the demon lord's death essentially possessing them, that he went back in time and became the person who became the hero's best friend, or that his soul was sent to the future and he became the best friend of a new hero?

Comment: He was reborn in the sense that his soul went back in time to a young boy. He was in the same village as the hero and still had his power that had intrigued the demon king in the first place. After he was reborn he begins to take the hero around and make her stronger and find her old party mates so that the demon king can be killed quicker.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is [I reincarnated for nothing](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/i-reincarnated-for-nothing/). This is not a manga.

Artpe is the 4th henchman in Demon King Army and he got beaten by Maetel.

The girl you remember is the 2nd henchman. In his 2nd life, he is reborn as a human and a chilhold friend of hero.

> “My life as a demon… No. My life as human is really…”
>
> Artpe was supposed to live a charmed life as the 4th strongest in the Demon King’s Army. However, his life was cut short by the hero’s blade.
>
> With his previous life’s memory intact, Artpe will live his life again. His boldness and resourcefulness will make him unrivalled!

Comment: Thank you. I’ve been dying. I guess the story was so well written the images stood out to me all this time even if I created them

Comment: "I Was the Weakest of the Four Heavenly Kings. Since I Have Reincarnated, I Want to Lead a Peaceful Life" is a manga that looks to be *inspired* by this novel.  at least to the point where most of the comments on the transaltion i found were stating the manga was a blatant rip off.  But, the translation I found also only started about a week before the question was asked.